# switch from 2d array to 1d (string)

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

I'm trying to read the input of a file that has something like

```
RGGG
RGYY 
YYYY
```

So, I'm trying to get a string array with each of the mentioned strings (and more if  so want to). So far, I got my input into a 2d array, yet I can't seem to figure out out to place the read chars into a string array.

```
char ch, file_name[100];
FILE *fp;

printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
scanf("%s", file_name);

fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); // read mode

if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

Matrix = (char **)malloc(4 * sizeof(char *));
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    Matrix[i] = (char*)malloc(8 * sizeof(char));

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < 4 && fscanf(fp, "%c", &Matrix[i][j++]) == 1);
}

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        printf("Matrix[%d][%d] = %c\n", i, j, Matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
```

And this is printing something like:

```
Matriz[0][0] = R
Matriz[0][1] = G
Matriz[0][2] = G
Matriz[0][3] = G
Matriz[0][4] =

Matriz[0][5] = R
Matriz[0][6] = G
Matriz[0][7] = Y
Matriz[1][0] = Y
Matriz[1][1] =

Matriz[1][2] = Y
Matriz[1][3] = Y
Matriz[1][4] = Y
Matriz[1][5] = Y
Matriz[1][6] = ═
Matriz[1][7] = ═
```

Would apreciate some insight on getting :

```
string[0] = RGGG
string[1] = RGYY
string[2] = YYYY
```

Am I just missing something really obvious? Thanks.

Comment: This has been answered a number of times. See [**return 2d array from function**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801092/return-2d-array-from-function/34802110#34802110) for starters. Use *line-oriented* input functions for reading *lines* of data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should skip the `'\n'` at the end of each line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < 4 && fscanf(fp, "%c", &Matrix[i][j++]) == 1);
    getc(fp);
}
```

Or simpler:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    memset(Matrix[i], 0, 8);
    fscanf(fp, "%7s", Matrix[i]);
}
```

And dump the strings this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("Matrix[%d] = %s\n", i, Matrix[i]);
}
```